# Sql server drop table not working

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with almost 45 million rows. I was updating a field of it with the query:

```
update tableName set columnX = Right(columnX, 10)
```

I didn't do tran or commit but directly ran the query. During the execution of query, after an hour unfortunately power failure occurred and now when i try to run select query it takes too much time and returns nothing. Even drop table doesn't work. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Try to shrink the table

Comment: It is possible that your database got corrupted - if power failure hit the SQL server too. Check database with `dbcc checkdb` command.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know what is the problem.

SQL server is rolling back your update statement..you can monitor the status of rollback ,using many ways

1.
 kill  sessionid with status only

2.By using DMV

```
select
der.session_id,
der.command,
der.status,
der.percent_complete
from sys.dm_exec_requests as der
where command IN ('killed/rollback',’rollback’)
```

Dont try to restart SQLServer,as this may prolong the status..